# How to get action that android application is trying removed/uninstalled from device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation

When user want to uninstall app from android device, I want user uninstall button click event for that application.

I am getting event of application is removed from device, but I want to show pop-up before application is removed. I am trying to achieve same like doing in 'App Lock' application.

Here is my code to get application removed event through broadcast receiver. But I am totally blank about uninstall button click or before pop-up click. Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CustomBroadcastReceiver mApplicationsReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mApplicationsReceiver=new CustomBroadcastReceiver();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_VERIFIED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH);

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DELETE); 
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT); 
        filter.addDataScheme("package"); 
        registerReceiver(mApplicationsReceiver, filter); 
    }





}


public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * This method captures the event when a package has been removed
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from CustomBroadcastReceiver");
        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();   
            System.out.println("L1123 : "+action);
            if (action.equals(intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED))   {
                //Log the event capture in the log file ...
                System.out.println("The package has been removed");
            }
        }
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bits.uninstallappdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_ADDED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <!--  <receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast is called after "An existing application package has been removed from the device." as documented in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Comment: Yes Kazuki your right, but I want action before ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED performed, so that I can prevent them.

Comment: @AmolWadekar you get the solution so please say how to do this. i also confuse about it but still is not working proper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to get the top activity in the task via `ActivityManager`, and check if it is the uninstall activity.

Core code:

```
ComponentName topActivity = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
String packageName = topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = topActivity.getClassName();
Log.v(TAG, "packageName" + packageName);
Log.v(TAG, "className" + className);

if ("com.android.packageinstaller".equals(packageName)
    && "com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity".equals(className)) {
//Do anything you want here
}
```

Comment: Hi Isaiah, can you please elaborate me , I really not get you. You mean I need to write service which check ActivityManager stack whose first activity is uninstall activity. Please guide me.
Because whenever I click on uninstall button of any application log cat get this message.


 ActivityManager: START {act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=package:MYPACKAGENAME cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.UninstallerActivity} from pid 6114

Comment: I mean you could determine whether the current activity is the uninstall activity or not. And then you could do anything you want. For detail, start a service and check every second, and if is the uninstall activity, intercept it and do something you want. See my edit for the details.

Comment: Thanks  Isaiah for your help, I really want this. Can you please guide me how I can get this activity through ActivityManager. Thanks ones again. I accept your answer.

Comment: @AmolWadekar My pleasure!  What do you mean by 'how i can get this activity through activitymanager'? Your could compare the `ComponentName`

Comment: I mean any tutorial for reference which is already implemented by you or any reference site of tutorial.

Comment: @AmolWadekar Sorry, i don't have any samples right now. And as you know, most of the 'App Lock' applications were implemented this way. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot Isaiah for sharing your logic. It works very well with service run every 1 second, But my issue is that, it gives me my activity on every applciation, I need that my activity should be able to show only if user clicks on uninstall button for my app.

Comment: "I need that my activity should be able to show only if user clicks on uninstall button for my app" -- Are you using the Device Administration APIs? If not, then the user should be able to uninstall your app if they want to. Preventing the use from doing so is very BAD for obvious reasons, and having apps in the ecosystem that behave this way is bad for the platform in general.

Answer (score 1):

The following permissions which you are using are granted to system apps only. Make sure you have rooted device to allow such permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: Permission "android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" is for the system apps only !